# On direct product of capable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G=H\times T$ such that $H$ is 2-generated p-group of class two and $H$ be abelian p- group. We know if $H$ and $T$ are capable groups, then $G$ is capable.

**Question:** Is the converse  correct or no? i.e

If $G$ is a capable group then  are  $T$ or $H$( both $H$ and $T$)  capable?

Comment: In general, you cannot hope for these kind of converses without conditions; just the fact that the product of two cyclic groups of the same order is always capable, but a nontrivial cyclic group is not, should tell you that this will not in general work; making one of the factors nilpotent does not, in my mind, give you enough leverage. The problems lie much deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be extraspecial of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$ (for odd $p$), and $T=C_p$. Then $G=H \times T$ is capable but $T$ is not.

We have $G = K/Z(K)$, where 
$$K= \langle a,b,c,d,e,f \mid [a,b]=c,[a,c]=e,[b,c]=f, [a,d]=e,
[b,d]=[c,d]=1,$$ $$a^p=b^p=d^p=1, e,f {\rm\  central} \rangle.$$

Answer (score 2):

The converse is not true in general. ￼Beyl, Felgner and Schmid presented a condition in which the capability of a direct product of finitely many of groups implies the capability of each of the factors [On groups occurring as center factor groups, Proposition 6.2](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869379903119/1-s2.0-0021869379903119-main.pdf?_tid=49a8b672-1af8-11e4-a447-00000aacb361&acdnat=1407061621_cc46c385228241a80c3b8a246786d514). Examples and counterexamples are also given in Remark $2.4$ and Example $2.1$ [here](http://profdoc.um.ac.ir/articles/a/1023202.pdf).